# Importing CSV to r and remove the rows of notes both at begining and middle

Tags: r, csv, batch-processing

I have several csv files recorded by air sensor (TSI Bluesky and AirAssure). This device records the data to its SD card. As with many machine-recorded files, the first 59 lines are notes that start with # to record basic information like serial numbers. These notes are easy to skip by adding `skip=59`. However, these notes could appear in the middle of the csv files by breaking the record. Meanwhile, the column names will repeat again. I have an example below.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #note |  |  |
| #note |  |  |
| #note |  |  |
| #note |  |  |
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| unit1 | unit2 | unit3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| #note |  |  |
| #note |  |  |
| #note |  |  |
| #note |  |  |
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| unit1 | unit2 | unit3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

How can I skip all the `note` and `unit` and only keep one column name and all the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code reads data from text, so if you are loading the csv file from some a folder, please check that the separator is "\t" or " "

The `comment.char` parameter filters the notes: `#note`

```
text <- 
"
#note       
#note       
#note       
#note       
col1    col2    col3
unit1   unit2   unit3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
#note       
#note       
#note       
#note       
col1    col2    col3
unit1   unit2   unit3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
"
library(dplyr)

df <- read.csv(text = text, comment.char = "#", sep = "\t")
filter(df, !col1 %in% c('col1', 'unit1'))
```

Output:

> ```
> col1 col2 col3
> 1    1    2    3
> 2    1    2    3
> 3    1    2    3
> 4    1    2    3
> 5    1    2    3
> 6    1    2    3
> ```